# Instructions Activity Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to create activity in which it would be explained how the app is supposed to be used. On a click on a button, I would like an Activity to be opened which has next and previous buttons on the bottom. So the first screen after the click on a button would show the first instruction and you can press next to see the next instruction which opens a new screen. After going through all the instructions, I would like a Finish button to return back to the main activity.

My question is can this be made in a single activity or is it actually more activities that differ only by the text and pictures they contain?

Comment: use `fragments` or you can use a library like [this](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro)

Comment: Best approach is to have single activity with multiple fragments using viewpager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done in only one activity(actually 2 if you include the main activity).
What you can do is have multiple TextViews, and when the next button is pressed, you can toggle that 1st instruction's visibility
. And so on for the next instructions. The Next/Previous buttons should determine what Textview is currently visible, so they can keep track what Textview to show next. Use switch statement